# difference between deploying spring application in tomcat and weblogic 10 servers

Tags: java, spring, jsp, weblogic-10.x

i have a spring application i deployed  in tomcat it is running fine but it is not running on weblogic server.
i did not written any big logic, my requirement is i want to forward request from jsp to controller class getMethod that's it. but this is not working in weblogic.here i am not using any servlet 3.0 jars

here is my web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
```

in my index.jsp i am just forwarding my request to one controller method

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<body>
<c:redirect url="/result"/>
</body>
</html>
```

and in my controller class i have a method with above url

```
@RequestMapping(value="/result")
    public String getResults(ModelMap map){

        map.put("userList",null);
        System.out.println("result page ...");
        return "result";

    }
```

anybody please tell me what am i missing here why it is not working in welogic and what is the difference.

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not working"? What happens when you try it on Weblogic? Do you get an error? If yes, then what is the error message?

Comment: thanks for your reply yes i am getting 404 error.

Comment: what is the full url that you try in tomcat and what is the url that you try in web logic?

Comment: Then the webapp is probably deployed under a different path than what you think on Weblogic. Find out what the path is that Weblogic deploys it at, and use the right path in the URL.

Comment: http://172.19.8.149:7001/BPMBatchSchedular  this is in weblogic server and http://localhost:8089/BPMBatchSchedular   this is in tomcat

Answer (score 0):

i think that when you have deployed to tomcat it had a context root , ie if you have developed your application with eclipse go to your project -> right click -> web project settings -> context root. This would probably be  BPMBatchSchedular for you.

But when you deployed to web logic you did not set a context root. In order to set a context root, create a weblogic.xml in the same directory where your web.xml is and put these lines of code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"

 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd 
 http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app 
 http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
      <context-root>/BPMBatchSchedular</context-root>

  </weblogic-web-app>
```

If you don't want to create a weblogic.xml file you can set the context root in the web logic web console

Comment: thanks for your reply here when i comment my code in index.jsp and give something like <h1>Hello</h1> and hitting my url it is printing the Hello message that means i think not the problem with context root.

Comment: and after hitting both url's with respect to containers it is appending the url as BPMBatchSchedular/result.